# NSUserDefaults EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm receiving an error message "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" because of "onlineLastUpdatedAt" and I don't understand why. Here's my code:

```
#define IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY @"iMonggoFetcher.ImonggoOnlineProductsLastUpdatedAt"

- (void) saveLastUpdatedAtDate{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *onlineLastUpdatedAt = [[defaults objectForKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY] mutableCopy];
    NSString *onlineLastUpdatedAtValue = [iMonggoFetcher lastUpdatedAtDate];

    if (!onlineLastUpdatedAt) onlineLastUpdatedAt = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if([onlineLastUpdatedAt containsObject:onlineLastUpdatedAtValue]){
        NSLog(@"onlineLastUpdated at contains a value for onlineLastUpdatedatValue");
        //[defaults setObject:onlineLastUpdatedAt forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"!onlineLastUpdated at contains a value for onlineLastUpdatedatValue");

        [onlineLastUpdatedAt addObject:onlineLastUpdatedAt];
        NSLog(@"mutablearray: %@", onlineLastUpdatedAt);
        [defaults setValue:onlineLastUpdatedAt forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    NSLog(@"added to defaults: %@ ",onlineLastUpdatedAtValue);
}
```

Comment: Verify that "onlineLastUpdatedAt" is initialized properly or not.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out. I missed type        [onlineLastUpdatedAt addObject:onlineLastUpdatedAt]; I added it to itself.

Comment: Whether it is `[onlineLastUpdatedAt addObject:onlineLastUpdatedAt];` or `[onlineLastUpdatedAt addObject:onlineLastUpdatedAtValue];`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `setValue:ForKey:` when you should be calling `setObject:ForKey`:

```
[defaults setValue:onlineLastUpdatedAt forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY];
```

Replace with:

```
[defaults setObject:onlineLastUpdatedAt forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY];
```

Comment: `setValue:...` is part of the Key-Value coding framework and is often confused for the `setObject...` methods implemented by collection objects.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot directly entered any object into the `NSUserDefaults`
First of all you have to convert that object into `NSData` or `NSMutableData`
try this

```
NSData *dataVal = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:onlineLastUpdatedAt];
[defaults setObject:dataVal forKey:IMONGGO_PRODUCTS_ONLINE_LAST_UPDATED_AT_KEY];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: are you sure because i am also found this error and when i used above code it works for me

Comment: Yes you can write you custom object to NSUserDefaults, for that you have to implement NSCoding protocol.. here is the link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE

Comment: Nope. Objects stored into NSUserDefaults directly must be [property lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303). Those are NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. And each object in an array or dictionary has to be a property list too. If you implement NSCoding you can use `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:];` as suggested by @HChouhan02

Comment: yes thats i am saying, with using my code you can insert any object like UIImage,NSDate.. etc.